# Tornado: catching exceptions inside asynchronous open

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, tornado, coroutine

I have problem with method *open* of *WebSocketHandler*.
I wrapped it with *gen.coroutine* for using async call inside (get access to redis). But got another problem, any errors inside open does not catches.

Example:

```
@gen.coroutine
def open(self):
    t = 8/0
    self._connection_id = yield self._generate_connection_id()
    self.write_message('...')
```

Method open is call inside *WebSocketProtocol._run_callback* :

```
def _run_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception:
        app_log.error("Uncaught exception in %s",
                      self.request.path, exc_info=True)
        self._abort()
```

This method hasn't any decorator, so method open return future and this exception doesn't handled.

So how can I use async method inside open, and handle exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, coroutines can only correctly be called by other coroutines, so when overriding a method of a base class like `WebSocketHandler.open`, unless that method is a coroutine or is documented as "may be a coroutine" or "may return a Future", it is not safe to make it a coroutine. `WebSocketHandler.open` may not be a coroutine (as of Tornado 4.1).

You may spawn a coroutine from open() with `IOLoop.spawn_callback`:

```
def open(self):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.async_open)

@gen.coroutine
def async_open(self):
    #...
```

Within `async_open`, you can handle errors as usual with try/except (`spawn_callback` also logs exceptions for you as a last resort). It is also your responsibility to deal with any timing issues that may arise between `async_open` and `on_message` or `on_close`, since those methods may be called before `async_open` completes.